# How do I make smoke dissipate after its stopped

Tags: smoke-simulation

So I have made a smoke simulation and set the starting point and the ending point of it. Is there any way I can make the smoke dissipate after it's stopped? Since right now it only freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create keyframes for the density of the emitter. If you bring the density to 0 the smoke would disappear.

[image]

Add also keyframes to decrease the temperature difference and the surface.

[image]