# smokeFire how to make it go away

Tags: smoke-simulation

smoke and fire sense how to get it to go away instead of just sitting there looking stuck, so I can move on to the next sense? Frame 1369 start 1400 stop Dissolve check, it just sits there flames sticking there.

[image][image]

[image]

Before the posted maybe a dup instructions,
Before the posted maybe a dup instructions, I dropped density to zero, and surface this is what I am left with that is all it now does, no big boom flame (still working on the smoke part)
( i have no idea how to formate this type. the first photo is before, the second photo is now, after the made adjustments now that little puff is all I am getting. Its late here now, if suggestions I'll take them, tomorrow I will experiment more when I have the time. )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make smoke dissipate after its stopped](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98423/how-do-i-make-smoke-dissipate-after-its-stopped)